# Registering a VS2008 plugin

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2008, plugins

I have a Visual Studio 2008 plugin DLL compiled and ready to use.  But ... how do i Install the plugin so that VS2008 sees it?

I'm sure I'm being completely thick but I just can't figure it out.

Any help would be much appreciated :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Place it in the Visual Studio 2008\Addins directory under your My Documents directory, you'll also need the manifest that goes with it (the .addin file)

Answer (score 1):

What about [documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/19dax6cz(VS.80).aspx)?